# F# not recognizing members of a record type

Tags: f#, recordtype

I am doing a simple mapping and the compiler doesn't recognize the record's members.
The image shows the type `OpeningHours` itself is clearly ok, with all 3 properties showing:

[image: Recognized record type with all members]

But hovering over the marked property shows:

> error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Day' is not defined.

Namespaces are all referenced and I even assign to the very same properties few lines below without any issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the constructor and properties, it looks like `OpeningHours` is defined as a class, not a record. The record syntax can't be used with classes, so the solution is either to change `OpeningHours` to a record, or to instantiate it using its existing constructor.

Answer (score 5):

`OpeningHours` is a class, not a record. This is one way to create an instance of the class:

```
OpeningHours(day = oh.Day, opens = oh.Opens, closes = oh.Closes)
```